# How to convert an object and its method into a function callable just with method’s arguments

Tags: c++, lambda, polymorphism, pointer-to-member

There is a function

```
template<typename Class, typename MemberFuncPtr>
auto makeCallback( Class* a, MemberFuncPtr func )
{
    return [a, func]( auto&&... args )
    {
        return ( a->*func )( std::forward<decltype( args )>( args )... );
    };
}
```

that converts an object pointer and its member method into a lambda capturing them that can be called later just with method’s arguments.
It works fine except for one situation, where the method is virtual and overridden in a derived class, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base
{
    virtual void g( int, int ) const
    {
        std::cout << "Base" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Derived : Base
{
    virtual void g( int, int ) const override
    {
        std::cout << "Derived" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename Class, typename MemberFuncPtr>
auto makeCallback( Class* a, MemberFuncPtr func )
{
    return [a, func]( auto&&... args )
    {
        return ( a->*func )( std::forward<decltype( args )>( args )... );
    };
}

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    auto cb = makeCallback( &d, &Base::g );
    cb( 1, 2 );

    return 0;
}
```

Here inspite of  `makeCallback( &d, &Base::g )` the program prints ‘Derived’.

Is there a way to modify only `makeCallback` (including any change of its signature) to receive ‘Base’ in program output?

Comment: That's how virtual functions work. A call through a "pointer-to-virtual-member-function" is a virtual call.

Comment: You can call Base method via `(&d)->Base::g(1, 2)` However, I am not sure, if it can be templatized.

Comment: Why do you want that? It is almost always an error.

Comment: I just want a simple method to convert a call of particular object method into a callable function. If I can call directly any method including methods from a parent class, why is it an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might do, with some change:

```
template<typename Class, typename MemberFuncPtr>
auto makeCallback( Class* a, MemberFuncPtr func )
{
    return [a, func]( auto&&... args )
    {
        return std::invoke(func, a, std::forward<decltype( args )>( args )... );
    };
}

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    auto cb = makeCallback(&d, [](auto obj, auto&&... args){ obj->Base::g(args...); });
    cb( 1, 2 );
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d2d8fd069947ab8)